# TikZ-Feynman, Chain of diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, feynman, tikz-feynman

I'm currently using Ti*k*Z-Feynman in order to generate Feynman diagrams, which works great so far; however, I'm currently stumped on how to do the following thing:

What I need is a sum of diagrams in a row, similar to a sum of vacuum polarizations when calculating running couplings for QED. Unfortunatly, I can not change the spacing between vertices [or can I?] so putting more than 10 vertices in a row is impractical and doesn't fit the paper.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a1) ;
\vertex[right =of a1] (a2);
\vertex[right =of a2] (a3);
...
\vertex[right =of a12] (a13);
\vertex[right =of a13] (a14);
\diagram* {
%Fermion & Gauge boson lines enter here
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you just want to decrease the spacing between your vertices? If so, you can use `right=<dist> of <node>`, or to change the default distance pass `every node/.style={node distance=<dist>}` as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment. (To set different horizontal and vertical defaults use `node distance=<y distance> and <x distance>`.) Or if you just want the whole diagram compressed horizontally you could use `xscale=<factor>` on the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Emma has already pointed you to the answer, but in addition to that are you using [Ti*k*Z-Feyn](https://github.com/transientlunatic/tikz-feyn) or [TikZ-Feynman](https://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/)?  Your syntax shows that you are using the latter, but then you say twice that you are using the former.  Unless there is a duplicate of Ti*k*Z-Feynman going by the name of Ti*k*Z-Feyn?

Comment: Emma, Thank you so much for a helpful answer!

JP-Ellis, Sorry for the confusion, was (is) using TikZ-Feyn -- very good tool! :)

Comment: @KjellT. Could you post a link to where you found Ti*k*Z-Feyn?  It's obviously not the Ti*k*Z-Feyn I linked to as the syntax is completely different and resembles (very much) the syntax of Ti*k*Z-Feynman.

Comment: Since there has been no further answer, and the syntax is from Ti*k*Z-Feynman, I have edited the question to refer to Ti*k*Z-Feynman instead of Ti*k*Z-Feyn.  Feel free to revert this edit if that is incorrect; though if you do, please let me know where you found Ti*k*Z-Feyn @KjellT.